# What is +++ and <<< on Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, operators

I just know from this [github project](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#usage) that Swift has `+++` and `<<<` "operators".

It's hard for me to search for this on google because `+++` and `<<<` maybe some kind of special characters and not showing up on search result at all. It's not even showing up on **questions that may already have your answer** section of Stack Overflow when I wrote the question title.

Can you explain briefly what are these weird operators for, and maybe some articles link for further reading?

Comment: As for searching symbols, use [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com).

Comment: Also appears to be custom operators based on the commit history. See [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/commit/ca9360184ae0f4c8cc7c48a0adb11e893a398e7f).

Comment: @tktsubota yeah, just realised that from other answer. Thanks for the SymbolHound, really helping!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those operators are not a part of Swift. They are defined within that repo and meaningful only within projects which include that module. Take a look at https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/master/Source/Core/Operators.swift#L27

`infix operator +++{ associativity left precedence 95 }`

and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html for more on implementing custom operators in Swift.

Comment: Oh I see! I wasn't aware that it's possible to define custom operator in Swift. Thanks!