# Weird syntax in swift

Tags: swift

I check out the Eureka project, and find out that they have some weird  syntax, like `<<<` and `+++`, which seems not common swift syntax, can anyone explain more?
[image]

Comment: Please don't paste a picture of code into your question. Just paste in the code.

Comment: They are custom operators which all mean add something to the form, section or array. You can see their definition by searching `infix operator +++` in the Find Navigtor (`Cmd + 4`) in Xcode or [on Github](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/search?q=infix+operator+%2B%2B%2B&unscoped_q=infix+operator+%2B%2B%2B).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is +++ and <<< on Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387414/what-is-and-on-swift)

Answer (score 3):

This difficulty finding information about custom operators is why you should not generally define custom operators.

Anyway, the Eureka custom operators are documented [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#operators):

> ### Operators
>
> Eureka includes custom operators to make form creation easy:
>
> #### +++       Add a section
>
> ```
> form +++ Section()
>
> // Chain it to add multiple Sections
> form +++ Section("First Section") +++ Section("Another Section")
>
> // Or use it with rows and get a blank section for free
> form +++ TextRow()
>      +++ TextRow()  // Each row will be on a separate section
> ```
>
> #### <<<       Insert a row
>
> ```
> form +++ Section()
>         <<< TextRow()
>         <<< DateRow()
>
> // Or implicitly create the Section
> form +++ TextRow()
>     <<< DateRow()
> ```
>
> #### +=        Append an array
>
> ```
> // Append Sections into a Form
> form += [Section("A"), Section("B"), Section("C")]
>
> // Append Rows into a Section
> section += [TextRow(), DateRow()]
> ```

Comment: I think one can select the operator and Jump To Definition, no?

Comment: That has worked on and off. I don't know if it's currently on. But if you want to google for more information, good luck…

Answer (score 1):

Those operators are not a part of Swift. They are defined in that project and meaningful only within projects.

Take a look at

https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/master/Source/Core/Operators.swift#L27

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

you can create your custom operators.